# Is DD-WRT wasting NVRAM space?

Tags: openwrt, flash-memory, dd-wrt

Please explain how I am misunderstanding these two commands:

```
root@DD-WRT:/tmp/var/log# cat /proc/mtd
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00080000 00020000 "boot"
mtd1: 00180000 00020000 "nvram"
mtd2: 01e00000 00020000 "linux"
mtd3: 01c60000 00020000 "rootfs"
mtd4: 05000000 00020000 "ddwrt"

root@DD-WRT:/tmp/var/log# nvram show >/dev/null
size: 52341 bytes (78731 left)
```

Flash pages on my router are 128 kB (0x20000)
and there are 12 pages (0x18/0x02) dedicated to NVRAM.
Why, then, is my total available NVRAM just one page (52341+78731 B)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the lack of answers, I conclude that these extra pages never
get written to, so yes, the NVRAM could be made much bigger.

To be clear, this also means that there is no flash wear-leveling
(i.e., the same page is being overwritten though cycling through 12 pages would
extend flash life 12x), so I guess my router might fail after
100,000 NVRAM overwrites.
Also, I found that the huge mtd4 is completely empty too,
so mtd1 is just the tip of the iceberg.
Please see the simple commands I used below to confirm these points
(all flash reads were empty except for the first half page of mtd1)
and correct me if I am wrong.

Of course, the developers are generous to write this code,
and I know it would be more complicated to optimize things for each system,
so I am not complaining
(honestly, aside from wear-leveling, I am not sure what I would do with more
memory, even if I had the skill to write firmware).

```
root@DD-WRT:/tmp/var/log# dd if=/dev/mtd1 count=1 skip=0
<REDACTED BUT NOT EMPTY>
1+0 records in
1+0 records out

root@DD-WRT:/tmp/var/log# dd if=/dev/mtd1 count=1 skip=102
<REDACTED BUT NOT EMPTY>
1+0 records in
1+0 records out

root@DD-WRT:/tmp/var/log# dd if=/dev/mtd1 count=1 skip=103
1+0 records in
1+0 records out

root@DD-WRT:/tmp/var/log# dd if=/dev/mtd1 count=1 skip=256
1+0 records in
1+0 records out

root@DD-WRT:/tmp/var/log# dd if=/dev/mtd1 count=1 skip=3071
1+0 records in
1+0 records out

root@DD-WRT:/tmp/var/log# dd if=/dev/mtd1 count=1 skip=3072
0+0 records in
0+0 records out


root@DD-WRT:/tmp/var/log# dd if=/dev/mtd4 count=1 skip=0
1+0 records in
1+0 records out

root@DD-WRT:/tmp/var/log# dd if=/dev/mtd4 count=1 skip=256
1+0 records in
1+0 records out

root@DD-WRT:/tmp/var/log# dd if=/dev/mtd4 count=1 skip=183839
1+0 records in
1+0 records out

root@DD-WRT:/tmp/var/log# dd if=/dev/mtd4 count=1 skip=183840
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
```